# quickfix Message Rejected: Invalid tag number:

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

I am using QuickFix/J 1.14.3 with fix4.2 as both Initiator and Acceptor.

On Acceptor I tried to disable all Validation checks in the config file as seen below. The fromAdmin() is called with the violating message. I am not sure I want to mess with the data dictionary but I thought by disabling all checks I could actually get the message. The acceptor sets a field as follows.
    newOrderSingle.setField(new IntField(6401, 79 ));

Any help would be appreciated.

```
UseDataDictionary=N
DefaultMarketPrice=12.30
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateUserDefinedMessages=N
UseDataDictionary=N

# ACCEPTOR SIMULATOR
[session]
SenderCompID=baml
TargetCompID=mjt
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SocketAcceptPort=9879
CheckCompID=N
```

Comment: `mess with the data dictionary` Of course yes. But never ever disable validation, which is wrong on so many levels. Validation check whether a message is correct according to the standards and the required fields are present or not. You might pass the testing but you will fail when you go into real world.

Comment: can you post the full text of the violating message? Which invalid tag number? If it's 6401 then [Fiximate](http://www.fixtradingcommunity.org/FIXimate/FIXimate3.0/index.html) says tag 6401 is unknown in FIX 4.2

Comment: This is the reject message:

<20170424-19:18:30, FIX.4.2:baml->mjt, incoming> (8=FIX.4.29=22935=D34=849=mjt50=VTRD52=20170424-19:18:30.11556=baml115=VTRD1=42490300D911=2171Morel00000000121=138=1040=244=29.6554=255=AAPL59=360=20170424-19:18:30.11277=O167=OPT200=201704201=1202=114204=0205=286401=7910=054)
<20170424-19:18:30, FIX.4.2:baml->mjt, event> (Message 8 Rejected: Invalid tag number:6401)

Comment: I am building a client connection to a BOA GES server. The server uses some custom fields with Fix4.2. It could be a couple of weeks before the test environment/certification is opened up to me. So I have embarked on making a simulator server. The simulator server is where I am having problems. I have taken the Exceptor example from 1.14.3 to be the simulator.

Comment: On a side note , I have downloaded 1.6.3 quickFixJ to build the latest Java code. I use IntelliJ as my IDE. I have problems converting from Maven as its build language. I have invested a couple of hours trying to build it but have not been sucessful.

Answer (score 2):

First of all add property

AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y

And use data dictionary it  allows to process groups.

UseDataDictionary=Y